# Error: ionic cordova run android --prod --release

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-directives

When I tried to build using the following command. How to resolve this problem. I am in doubt is this problem occur because of the ionic has been updated.

Even if i tried removing AccountPage from the directive the problem occurs for the next page ConfirmationPage.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

**Error**
[image]

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TransactionPage } from '../pages/transaction/transaction';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { SendPage } from '../pages/send/send';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';
import { ConfirmationPage } from '../pages/confirmation/confirmation';
import { JoinPage } from '../pages/join/join';
import { AccountPage } from '../pages/account/account';
import { OtpPage } from '../pages/otp/otp';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { TransactionDataProvider } from '../providers/transaction-data/transaction-data';
import { SenderProvider } from '../providers/sender/sender';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service/auth-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TransactionPage,
    LoginPage,
    SendPage,
    DetailPage,
    ConfirmationPage,
    JoinPage,
    OtpPage,
    AccountPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TransactionPage,
    LoginPage,
    SendPage,
    DetailPage,
    ConfirmationPage,
    JoinPage,
    OtpPage,
    AccountPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    TransactionDataProvider,
    SenderProvider,
    AuthServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `<page-name>.module.ts` file from all pages when you use `--prod.`

Remove module file from folder generated and remove `@IonicPage()` from `<page-name>.ts` file and remove `IonicPage import`.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing what Paresh said you'll need to see what architecture you're using. Are you lazy loading your pages or not?

The latest versions of ionic-cli generates pages ready for lazy loading with a module for the specific page and the `@IonicPage()` decorator in the page `.ts` file. Since you're declaring every page on `app.module` there's a (big) chance that you're not lazy loading, but when you're pushing a page or anything like this and you're not importing the page to use and you're just passing the page name as a string then you're lazy loading.

So if you're using lazy loading then you need to remove all imports and declarations of pages from your `app.module.ts` declarations and entryComponents.

If you're not lazy loading in every page folder you'll need to delete the `<page>.module.ts` and remove the `@IonicPage()` from the page `.ts` file.

Comment: I am not using lazy load. In the middle of my development ionic came with update for @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2 ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3. I did update it

Comment: But then removing the auto generated page modules worked for you? When generating a page for a project whose you're not using lazy loading use the flag `--no-module`, like `ionic g page yourPageName --no-module` and it'll prevent the CLI from generating a module.

Comment: Thank you, both. It works when I deleted the modules.ts and imports.